# laravel 5 call method from controller in view

Tags: laravel, methods, view, controller, call

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);
    \Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart::add($id, $product->name, 1, $product->price);
}
```

When I call it from my view

```
<a href="{{\App\Http\Controllers\CartController::edit($productItem->id)}} " class="item_add">
```

Im getting error:

```
Non-static method App\Http\Controllers\CartController::edit() should not be called statically
```

How shall I properly call it?

Comment: Can you show the `Route` you have set up for `CartController@edit`?

Comment: Route::resource('cart','CartController');

Comment: Try this: `<a href="{{ app()->make(\App\Http\Controllers\CartController::class)->edit($productItem->id) }}">`, although why you wouldn't just assign this function to a route and use `<a href="{{ url("/route/to/function") }}">` is beyond me...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't to set the link like that:

```
<a href="{{\App\Http\Controllers\CartController::edit($productItem->id)}} "
```

But you have to set it like that:

```
url('cart/edit/' . $productItem->id)
```

Comment: @RossWilson but how else can I call it?

Comment: I changed it . So you have to change the link href .. I think it's not the function that been called using Route.

Comment: Do you try it @Ronald?

Comment: but the problem is I don't want to go to another page. For example, I press -add to cart- button which is a href, and I wanna stay in the page

Comment: @Ronald If you don't want the page to redirect/refresh you'll have to use something like ajax to submit the request for you. Either way, you'll need to provide the correct url and Abdulkareem Mohammed's answer provides you with a way to do that.

Comment: You won't go to another page. You change the link to be correct:
`<a href="{{\App\Http\Controllers\CartController::edit($productItem->id)}} " class="item_add">` to be `<a href="{{ url('cat/edit/' . $productItem->id) }} " class="item_add">`

Comment: @RossWilson which method should I use in ajax? get or head? there's only these 2 methods in edit method. I don't understand how get method will actually "post" product in the cart

Comment: But if you want to do that without **reloading** the page, You have to use ajax and you can't at all call the `edit($id)` method as you called it in static way using `::` because it's static method and you can't define it as static because it's used by the route

Comment: @AbdulkareemMohammed when I have  <a href="{{ url('cart/'.$productItem->id.'/edit/')}}  ", and I click it, im getting redirrected to http://site.loc/cart/9/edit

Comment: @Ronald That's what happens when you click an `<a href="...">`; If you don't want the page to refresh, you'll need to use AJAX

Comment: @TimLewis Now I understand, but which method of edit function should I use for ajax: get or head?

Comment: @Ronald Neither. You would use either `PUT` or `PATCH`.

Comment: Or `POST`, So a basic jQuery/Ajax call would be something like `$.post(url, postData, function(data){ ... });` where `url` is the url that points to the `edit()` function (as defined in `Routes.php` (`Route::post("url", "Controller@edit");`), `postData` is an object containing all necessary data you'd be sending to the function (like `_token` for `POST` requests), and `function(data){ ... }` would be where you handle the returned response from the `edit()` function.

Comment: @TimLewis But when I watch routes with php artisan route:list, I see that edit method contains only get and head, not put/get/patch. Doesn't it mean that I cant combine this method with put/get/patch?

Comment: If the function is meant to return data only, it would be a `GET` request. If the function is meant to accept some data and handle it, that would be a `POST` request (or `PUT`, `PATCH`, whatever). I don't know what this edit function is supposed to do, so I can't advise much further.

Comment: @Ronald Sorry. Yes, edit should be `get` or `head`. The update method should be `put` or `patch`. The convention is to (as Tim Lewis said) use the update method to actually edit your resources. The edit method is meant to be used to display the form page that would submit to update.

Comment: @RossWilson can u tell me please why my ajax script doesn't work? 

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".item-add").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url:$('.item_add').attr('href'),
            data:data,
            type:'PUT',
            dataType:'JSON',
            success: function(html){
               if(html.success)
                {
                    alert('Success!');
                    
                }
            
        });
    });

});

Im still getting redirected to another page ;_;

Comment: You have to `return false;` or `e.preventDefault()` not to redirect to another page.

Comment: @AbdulkareemMohammed tried both, still getting redirected :c

Comment: I would imagine it's the missing `}` after your success method. Check your browser console. Also, if problems persist with your jQuery code please could you create a new question as it going outside of the scope of this one :)

Comment: @RossWilson okie (:

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a URL to a controller action by using the `action` helper method:

```
<a href="{{ action('CartController@edit', [$productItem->id]) }}" class="item_add">
```

Answer (score 0):

What the...lol...create a separate route...every other way you're attempting to do it should be deeply frowned upon and aborted (including some of the suggested answers/comments), IMO.

Note, I also changed "edit" to "add", based off the naming convention of the cart library you're using.

***In routes.php add (notice I named the route - best practice):***

```
Route::get('cart/add/{id}', ['as' => 'cart.add', 'uses' => 'CartController@add']);
```

***In view, call it like so:***

```
<a href="{{ route('cart.add', [$productItem]) }}">Add</a>
```

***In your controller, do something along these lines:***

```
public function add($id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);
    Cart::add($id, $product->name, 1, $product->price);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

> ***PS:*** Bit confused on why you're calling the facade like that. In `config/app.php` under aliases, add this: `'Cart' => Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart::class,`.
>
> Then in your controller, inject at the top as `use Cart;`. From there,
>   just use `Cart::add($id, $product->name, 1, $product->price);` in your
>   method.